# log rotation fails for dnsmasq on osx using newsyslog

Tags: osx, logs, dnsmasq

I am running dnsmasq on OSX.

I am also using newsyslog to rotate log files. Here is the `/etc/newsyslog.d/dnsmasq.conf`

```
# logfilename          [owner:group]    mode count size   when  flags [/pid_file] [sig_num]
/var/log/dnsmasq.log   nobody:admin     640  5     10000  *     Z
```

Logs are correctly rotated but when this happens a single line is written to the new log file but then all logging stops until I restart `dnsmasq`.

```
Nov  2 15:30:00 nexus newsyslog[1932]: logfile turned over due to size>10000K
```

Finally, here is my `/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/opt/dnsmasq/sbin/dnsmasq</string>
      <string>--keep-in-foreground</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Any idea how to best fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a pid_file and sig_num to dnsmasq.conf like so:

```
# logfilename          [owner:group]    mode count size   when  flags [/pid_file]           [sig_num]
/var/log/dnsmasq.log   nobody:admin     640  5     10000  *     Z     /var/run/dnsmasq.pid  31
```

sig_num 31 is SIGUSR2 which will tell dnsmasq to close and reopen its log file.